# How do I know the Canon 6d shutter count via software?

Tags: canon, shutter-actuations, canon-6d

How do I know the Canon 6d shutter count via software, since it's not on the EXIF, and EOSInfo, gPhoto, MagicLantern don't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "MagicLantern don't work"? You're having troubles getting it working, or it's working, but doesn't show the shutter count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gday.

I have a 6d.
Magic lantern shows me the shutter count. I dunno why you're not seeing it. It's on the menu with 0101 on it. Near the bottom. It displays two numbers separated with a +.
The numbers before the + are photos taken. The numbers after the + are live view actuations.

Alternatively, you can use DSLR controller ($8 on Google Play) and that will also tell you the number of photos taken, but not the live view actuations.

have a nice day.

Comment: Are you just using the dev version of magic lantern for the 6D? I didn't think a full "release" was out yet.

Comment: Gday. I'm using "[113] Check4Regression.zip" from https://bitbucket.org/OtherOnePercent/tragic-lantern-6d/downloads There isn't a "proper release", but this version has the features that I love working.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike Nikon, Canon doesn't provide shutter actuation count in the EXIF data.

For some of Canon DSLRs this is possible by using third-party applications such as [gPhoto2](http://www.gphoto.org/), [EOScount](http://eoscount.com/) or [EOSInfo](http://astrojargon.net/EOSInfo.aspx).

Canon 6D has a DIGIC 5+ processor, and unfortunately I can't say for sure if any of the mentioned application support Canon 6D or not.

**[EOScount](http://eoscount.com/FAQ.aspx#cameras_supported)** says they can read information from some DIGIC 5 cameras, so I suggest you to try it.

**Reading shutter count information is also possible at authorized Canon service centers.**

Comment: It is worth pointing out that he specifically said that EOSInfo and gPhoto did not work in the question.

Comment: Thanks, above I meant EOScount, but somehow I typed EOSinfo... fixed now.

Comment: I tried EOSCount and it dont even recognize the connected camera. And even if it did, i would have to pay to read the info: http://eoscount.com/FAQ.aspx#reading_process

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious first thing to check is if your camera is set to continuous file naming or auto reset. If it is set to continuous file naming you likely can just look at your existing file names, such as IMG_5000.jpg or IMG_5000.CR2, then determine if you have more than one file on your computer with that name. If you only have one file with that name, you either deleted it or have only shot 5000 shots total.

Clearly this is not a definitive answer, but in many cases this will work. If you never changed this setting, saved most of your images, and are the first owner - this method works.

Many owners of DSLRs never take over 9,999 shots ever, believe it or not, so it is possible that you don't even need to have any saved files to determine shot count if it is under 10,000. Just take a new shot, look at the file name, and you have your shutter count.

Comment: i took 10k shots in 1 week.

Comment: I would also dispute this answer as there is a filenaming option on my camera to reset the number every time the CF card is formatted.  Which I do after I've downloaded the images from every shoot!  Additionally are you sure most DSLR users never take over 9,999 shots?! I am only an amateur and I've taken tens of thousands of photos over the years!

Comment: @mike - I don't know what you are disputing beyond your obvious misunderstanding of the cameras features and my answer. Your camera is not in _continuous_ file naming, thus this answer does not apply. Continuous file naming is the *default*, which you have changed. This answer does apply to those who have not altered that setting.

Comment: @ariel - If you are truly taking 10,000 shots per week, on any kind of recurring basis, expect the 6D to fail very soon. It is not meant for that kind of use. I also wouldn't be worried about a shutter count if you really are using it in that way, as it is almost expected to fail, it is only rated to 100,000.

Comment: @mike - I did not say that _most_ DSLR users never take over 9,999 shots, I said that _MANY_ never do. This distinction is very important if you are going to tell me I am wrong. To answer your question, yes I am absolutely positive that this is a fact. Yes out of the users of this site, I'm sure most if not all of us have taken over 10,000 shots with a camera, but out of the millions who buy DSLRs, that is simply not the case. People buy them and don't use them. Look at the used market for proof.

Comment: @dpollitt I did not mean to offend you, I just read the word 'many' and was surprised by it as I know I'm not alone in changing that setting amongst my photography friends in real life.  Additionally because I know a lot of amateur togs (I'm a member of a club) maybe I have a distorted view of what 'many' means.  Then I used the wrong word 'most' in my response.  Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a macOS app called **[EOS Inspector](https://eosinspector.app)** that reads shutter actuations count.

You can [download it on the Mac App Store](https://eosinspector.app/appstore).

Update: Now I can say for sure that it works with EOS 6D .

Comment: Does it work for this model in specific?

Comment: @mattdm I maintain a list of supported cameras on this page: http://eosinspectorapp.com/support. EOS Inspector should work with EOS 6D, at least some testers told me so. I didn't had an opportunity to verify it myself.

Comment: The camera compatibility table is now available at the technical specifications page: https://eosinspector.app/specs

Answer (score 1):

ShutterCount for Mac. It is certified to work with the Canon 6D.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/shuttercount/id720123827?mt=12
Dave